# Unable to access locally hosted .php app from off network ip's

Tags: php, apache2

I am running a Ubuntu 22.04 home server
I have apache2 and php installed

```
# which php
/usr/bin/php

# which apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
```

I wrote a little .php app for a the game Starfield i recently picked up and I am hosting it off a local server at home.

I set the page to be used on port 81

I have a domain set up through google and it has a working DNS entry.

I know its working as I have a few other services that are connecting on other ports without issue on external access.

I put the files in /var/www/html/Starfiled/

```
root@Asus-Ubuntu:[/var/www/html/Starfield]# ll
total 52K
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4.0K Sep 17 20:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root     4.0K Sep 16 21:26 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  844 Sep 16 21:46 bootstrap.php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 1.4K Sep 17 00:38 btn_donate_TN.gif*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 2.3K Sep 16 22:55 filter.php*
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data 4.0K Sep 17 10:41 .git/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   66 Sep 16 21:25 .gitattributes*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  533 Sep 17 19:14 .htaccess*
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   21 Sep 17 20:21 index2.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 2.4K Sep 17 00:46 index.php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  176 Sep 16 21:46 pdo.php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 1.5K Sep 16 22:15 planets.php*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data  608 Sep 17 10:31 util.php*
```

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName xxxx
        ServerAdmin xxxxxx
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory "/var/www/html/phpsysinfo">
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName xxxx
    ServerAdmin xxxxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Starfield

    <Directory "/var/www/html/Starfield">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/starfield-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/starfield-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have verified my router has the correct port forwarding for this page.

```
#   Service Name    External Starting Port  Internal Starting Port  Internal IP address
1   xxxxxx  3001-3001   3001-3001   192.168.1.27
2   xxxxxx  8096-8096   8096-8096   192.168.1.27
3   xxxxxx  2342-2342   2342-2342   192.168.1.27
4   HTTP    81-81   81-81   192.168.1.27
```

I am listening on port 81

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep :81
tcp6       0      0 :::81                   :::*                    LISTEN      549421/apache2
```

firewall is currently not active

```
# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

my apache2.conf

```
ServerName wiatech.xyz

Listen 81

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn


IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

I am able to load the page from within my local network on any device however when any external ip tries to connect they get the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

I am still quite green when it comes to running a self hosted server and looking for assistance to get the page working.  Thank you for any help provided.

I have tried multiple ports 80/8080/8085/81 result the same.  I am able to access the page locally but any connection not from within my home network gets timed out.

As my other services work off net I can only assume its something with apache2 configuration.

Comment: I have a Windows 11 machine that I can access the site from my chrome browser by internal IP and domain name

http://192.168.1.27:81    
http://wiatech.xyz:81

But when i turn on a VPN and try the same i get timeout errors.  


When i try from my phone with wifi on i can load the page.  
When i try from my phone with wifi off i am unable to load the page.

Comment: Pls turn off the VPN and try again

Comment: Turning the VPN off allows the page to load as expected.  

And as for your second question.

As for  the lines   "Deny from all"  and "Allow from 192.168.1.0/24"

Those are set under a different <Direcotry> </Directory> for a the phpSysInfo folder i have in my /var/www/html/ directory.  

As far as i know that should not affect the /var/www/html/Starfield folder and files.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that I want to have the page reachable from off network for some friends of mine to use as well and they are getting the ERR-CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.   I can replicate that by using a "Off-Net" connection ie VPN.   

Yes I know it works fine on my local net but that is not the issue.

Comment: Possibly not every DNS server knows your site yet. Possibly VPN doesn't like outbound on port 81. There are a few possibilities. Generally a self hosted server is always a hassle, much easier and more secure to host online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this was an ISP issue.

I had an unrelated problem with access to Disney+ saying I was not in an approved region.

So after forcing a change of my IP to my residence to get Disney+ to work.  I went back to look further into the web app hosting issue it was working and could be accessed from outside my home network.

The only change was my IP provided by my ISP.  So somehow that IP got buggy and was my problem.